# How to show another content over ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have the following problem:

I have `MainActivity`, where `ViewPager` is placed. Page of `ViewPager` is Fragment, which contains `imageview` and several `textviews`. When user clicks on the image, another content should be shown. And probably I don't understand how can I do it. As I know, I can't place `FrameLayout` on my Page `Fragment` and here show another fragment with needable content. Also I cannot place this fragment on MainActivity, as I cannot change it from my fragment (and if I want to change ViewPager on my Fragment with needable content, I cannot catch clicks on ImageView). I found one solution: to have 2 layouts on Page Fragment (first for ViewPager and second for content, which will be shown after), and change their visibility each time, but I don't think that this is the best idea. So, maybe you have better variants?

**UPD**

I need form this

[image]

after clicking on image get this:

[image]

Comment: what don't just use a custom `dialog`?

Comment: @lvl4fi4, probably I cannot understand how can I do it with dialog. I updated the question and showed what I need to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `VeiwSwitcher` wich you can learn about it [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher)

> `public class ViewSwitcher extends ViewAnimator` that switches between two views, and has a factory from which these views are created. You can either use the factory to create the views, or add them yourself. A ViewSwitcher can only have two child views, of which only one is shown at a time.

for example :

```
<ViewSwitcher
    android:id="@+id/viewSwitcher1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:inAnimation="@android:anim/slide_in_left" >

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    //Content of first layout 

    </LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/view2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
   //Content of second layout

    </LinearLayout>
</ViewSwitcher>
```

so basically you have Two `ViewGroup` and first one is visible to user and second one is hidden . and you can only have Two `View` in side of `ViewSwitcher` and you can switch between them with a `Button` :

```
viewSwitcher =   (ViewSwitcher)findViewById(R.id.viewSwitcher1);
    myFirstView= findViewById(R.id.view1);
    mySecondView = findViewById(R.id.view2);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (viewSwitcher.getCurrentView() != myFirstView){

                viewSwitcher.showPrevious(); 
            } else if (viewSwitcher.getCurrentView() != mySecondView){

                viewSwitcher.showNext();
            }
        }
    });
```

and it dos not matter what kind of `view` or `id` used for those Two views.

so just put `ViewSwitcher` in your `Fragment` layout and put your image through xml or programmatically . and use Two `Button` one in the first layout and one in the second layout to switch between them. hope this works for you. you can also use `Dialog` but in your case it will make it ugly!